# How to simplify the cubic radical $\sqrt[3]{a\sqrt{b}-c}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, nested-radicals

> How to simplify the cubic radical $\sqrt[3]{a\sqrt{b}-c}$ ?

So I encountered a particular problem in chapter of surds and radicals to find the cube root of $38\sqrt{14}-100\sqrt{2}$ .

So I took out 2√2 common leaving to find out the cube root of $\sqrt[3]{19\sqrt{7}-50}$

*From I'm having no good idea to continue further ..*

Comment: Hint: $50^2-19^2\cdot 7=(-3)^3.$

Comment: You can't in general simplify such, but you can for these particular $a,b,c.$

Comment: Assume the answer is nice and integral, and solve it from there.

Comment: In general you'll need $c^2-a^2b$ a perfect cube, and even then, you won't always get a closed form.

Comment: A simple counter-example would be $2\sqrt 2-3,$ which has $c^2-a^2b=1,$ but there is no good closed form for the cube root.

Comment: @Arthur yeah that's my doubt why to assume and on what basis to assume that it would be some integral ?

Comment: Because if the answer is nice and integral, then that assumption will lead you to your answer. And if the answer isn't nice and integral, then making the assumption that it is nice will lead to some impossibility, which will tell you the answer is likely to be pretty ugly.

Comment: and because Thomas Andrews' first comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a nice solution, which I will here take to mean integral, then it must be that $-50+19\sqrt 7=(a+b\sqrt7)^3$ with nice $a,b$. There are several things we can tell from this, most immediately that

- $a^3+21ab^2=-50$
- $3a^2b+7b^3=19$

If $a$ and $b$ really are nice, then the first line tells us that $a$ is negative and a divisor of $50$ (since $a^2+21b^2$ is necessarily positive). Similarly we find that $b$ is positive and a divisor of $19$.

That makes it a total of twelve possibilities to check. Considering that $3a^2+7b^2$ is also a divisor of $19$, that narrows it down a lot further.

Comment: Yeah thanks i got the idea

Answer (score 1):

Remember that we have: $$ (a-b) ^3 = a^3 -3a^2 b + 3 a b^2 - b^3.$$

You're already very close to the answer. First you should notice that your formula is already of the form of $(x-y)$, and so the first thing you should think of is how can we rewrite our result into equation 1.

We're trying to find $a$ and $b$ such that $(a-b) ^3 = 19\sqrt{7} - 50.$

Another hint is that $ \sqrt{7}^3 = 7\sqrt{7} $ and that $2^3 = 8.$

Finally you'll obtain : $(\sqrt{7}-2)^3 =  19\sqrt{7} - 50.$

Answer (score 1):

OP's $\;\sqrt[3]{19\sqrt{7}-50}\;$ is one of the cases covered by my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4447889/291201).

> Therefore a sufficient condition for $\,a,b = \sqrt[3]{m \sqrt{p} \pm n\sqrt{q}}\,$ to denest is for $\,m^2 \cdot p - n^2 \cdot q\,$ to be the cube of a rational $\,r\,$, and for the cubic $\,p\, t'^{\,3} - 3r\, t' - 2m\,$ to have an appropriate rational root, and in that case $\,a,b = \frac{1}{2}\left(t'\,\sqrt{p} \pm \sqrt{t'^{\,2} p-4r}\right)\,$.

For $\,a,b = \sqrt[3]{19\sqrt{7}\pm 50}\,$:

- $m=19\,$, $\,p=7\,$, $\,n=\pm 50\,$, $\,q=1\,$;
- $m^2 \cdot p - n^2 \cdot q$ $= 19^2 \cdot 7 - (\pm 50)^2 \cdot 1$ $= 27$ $=3^3$ $\implies r=3\,$;
- $0 = p\, t'^{\,3} - 3r\, t' - 2m = 7 t'^{\,3} - 9 t' - 38\,$ with the only real root $\,t' = 2\,$.

Then:

$$
a,b = \frac{1}{2}\left(t'\,\sqrt{p} \pm \sqrt{t'^{\,2} p - 4r}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(2 \cdot \sqrt{7} \pm \sqrt{2^2 \cdot 7 - 4 \cdot 3}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(2\sqrt{7} \pm \sqrt{16}\right) = \sqrt{7} \pm 2$$

Answer (score 0):

So , the idea is $\sqrt[3]{19\sqrt{7}-50}$ will be of the form $a\sqrt{7}-b$ . Therefore,

Let $\sqrt[3]{19\sqrt{7}-50} = a\sqrt{7}-b$ .

Then, $\sqrt[3]{19\sqrt{7}+50} = a\sqrt{7}+b$

By multiplying , $3 = 7a^2-b^2$ ...(1)

And $19\sqrt{7}-50=7\sqrt{7}a^3-21a^2b+3\sqrt{7}ab^2-b^3$

whence, $50 = 21a^2b+b^3$ ...(2)

From (1) and (2), $b = 2$

Hence, $a=1$, $b=2$ ($a$ should be obviously positive in order to make the cube root positive)
$$\therefore \sqrt[3]{19\sqrt{7}-50} = \sqrt{7}-2$$